# is forelse remove in laravel 4.2.4?

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-blade

I was trying to use the @forelse in laravel but it give me this error

```
 Undefined variable: data
```

is @forelse remove from laravel 4.2.4? because that's the version that i am using. This is my code

in my view

```
@forelse ($result as $data)
  <tr><td> $data->name </td></tr>
@empty
  <tr><td>No name match</td></tr>
@endforelse
```

in my controller

```
$result = User::find(1)->get();
return View::make('view')->with('result', $result);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think `@forelse` has been around since Laravel 3. I could be wrong. I know it was removed at some point though. You need to use a standard `@if` and `@foreach` now.

```
@if (empty($result))
  <tr><td>No name match</td></tr>
@else
  @foreach ($result as $data)
    <tr><td> $data->name </td></tr>
  @endforeach
@endif
```

**UPDATE**

As pointed out by Antonio it was brought back and is available in **v4.2.7+**, so you'll need to update if you want it.

Comment: oh, okay. hmm. because when browsing the laravel documentation, there's a forelse in the list. thank you very much

Comment: Forelse was brought back in july: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blame/4.2/src/Illuminate/View/Compilers/BladeCompiler.php#L446

Comment: Have updated answer to include the revival of `forelse` and to include the versions where it's available.

Comment: I'm on 4.2.11 and I couldn't seem to get it working. It kept telling me the variable was undefined. Which, it was. But the way you showed in your answer works great.

Answer (score 2):

I found the same thing. In the laracast video on Laravel 5 it is mentioned. Although right after he explains that a better practice is using the if else with the count function:

```
@if (count($result))
  has result
@ifelse
  has no result
@endif
```